# How to create mysql server on azure using python script

Tags: python-2.7, azure, azure-mysql-database

I have to create mysql server on azure using python script

Is there any way to create it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this should be possible using the [Azure Python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-install?view=azure-python).

This might be what you are looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-rdbms/azure.mgmt.rdbms.mysql.operations.servers_operations.serversoperations?view=azure-python

Comment: a bunch of samples available here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/?products=azure-resource-manager&platform=python&sort=0